# PHP uploading an image by posting a form

Tags: php

i am trying to upload image through following code.
although my if condition is executing as shown below but image is not moving to the specified path given by me. my code is below.
here is my html code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="catcher.php" method="POST">
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

and here is my php code

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/xampp/project/';
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

can any body point out whats wrong with my code i mean why the image i am trying to upload is not moving to the specified path,,

Comment: You forgot the destination file name in the `$uploaddir`.

Comment: Why are you echo'ing _pre_ before the if statement?

Comment: The path you are specifying is absolute - it's expecting a directory called `xampp` to exist at the root, which I'm guessing it does not. Remember that your PHP script most likely has a working directory of the directory in which it resides, try specifying a relative path - you could start by removing the leading `/`. You will also need to specify a file name, not just a directory path.

Comment: i have used the file name too but still nt working @randle 
i have tried this too like
$uploaddir = '/xampp/project/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir))

Comment: You also need to check its an image, else you will get **hacked**

Comment: @elise that pre is just to print my array as it is in a well formatted form that is nt ht eissue

Comment: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php6545.tmp' to 'xampp/experiment/images/Koala.jpg
this is the warning i am getting 
but path is present there i dont know what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) requires the second parameter to be destination file, not directory.

You could do:

```
$filename = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $filename)){
// ...
```

But there is good chance that multiple users will try to upload files with the same name, so I strictly recommend to handle this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $folder =  "../images/stories/";
$result =   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], $folder.$filename);
```

Give destination folder name. (In above code, $folder is destination path variable)
You can see detail on this function:

```
function upload($name,$tmp_name){   

$fileextarr=explode('.',$name);
$fileextarr[0];
$fileext=$fileextarr[count($fileextarr)-1];
$fpath = "../images/stories/lab_excel/";
$filename = ereg_replace(" ","_",$fileextarr[0]).'.'.$fileext;


//You can use restriction on file extensions also. (not necessary)

if($fileext=="xls" || $fileext=="xlsx" || $fileext=="doc"|| $fileext=="docx" || $fileext=="jpeg" || $fileext=="png" || $fileext=="gif" || $fileext=="tiff" || $fileext=="bmp" || $fileext=="jpg")
{
    $uploadedfile = $filename;

}

//Here is the use of destination path:



 $folder =  "../images/stories/lab_excel/";
$result =   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], $folder.$filename);

/*echo $folder.$_FILES['excel']['name'];
die();*/

if($result){
$msg="File Uploaded Successfully";
    return $folder.$filename;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: i just found out there was some problem with my directory name i just used ./ istead of full path and it worked fine then,,,